# Refresh Razor page on new data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, signalr

Following a few tutorials, I've got an ASP.NET MVC app working that shows a dashboard of employees in/out & issued equipment. It's standard stuff with nothing fancy, SQL Server, Azure, scaffolding & Razor pages. When changes are made to database by adding new employees, the full screen dashboard view doesn't update so I hacked a 10 second refresh on it (Yuck), which also works but instead I want to refresh data realtime when there are changes. Following more tutorials, I am able to use SignalR to put sample text into a div I created on the dashboard page. I am close to what I need but missing the ability to update the page with actual data, not just sample text. Is there a way to get SignalR to refresh/reload the entire page in controller or view?

This is the nonsense code in my hub that I am hoping for:

```
await _messageBrokerHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("location.reload(true)");
```

Of course, this is silly. I don't see any tutorials using razor page code, just javascript or Blazor so I am questioning my understanding/implementation of SignalR.

Here is a sample of my Razor partial code:

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr class="@(item.ScanDateIn<DateTime.Today ? "text-danger":"" )">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Plate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Van)
        </td>
        <td>
            @(item.ScanDateIn<DateTime.Today ? "Missed Punch Out": @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScanTimeOut) )
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Here's the controller sample:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index2()
{
    var Drivers = driverRepository.GetTodaysDrivers();

    if (Drivers == null)
    {
        RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return PartialView(await Drivers);
}
```

Tutorial SignalR sample code:

```
   protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Driver driver = new Driver() { Id = 1, Name = "Neo", ScanDateIn = DateTime.Now, Phone = "555-1212", Plate = "Matrix1" };

            var eventMessage = new EventMessage($"Id_{ driver.Id.ToString():N}", $"Title_{driver.Name:N}", driver.ScanDateIn);

            await _messageBrokerHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("onMessageReceived", eventMessage, stoppingToken);

        }
```

SignalR Javascript sample code (All this should be erased and this is where I think the refresh page code show go for the controller or view??)

```
let messageCount = 0;

signalrConnection.on("onMessageReceived", function (eventMessage) {
    messageCount++;
    const msgCountH4 = document.getElementById("messageCount");
    msgCountH4.innerText = "Messages: " + messageCount.toString();
    const ul = document.getElementById("messages");
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = messageCount.toString();
   for (const property in eventMessage) {
        const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        const classAttrib = document.createAttribute("style");
        classAttrib.value = "font-size: 80%;";
        newDiv.setAttributeNode(classAttrib);
        const newContent = document.createTextNode(`${property}: ${eventMessage[property]}`);
        newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
        li.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
    ul.appendChild(li);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
});
```

If you made it this far, thanks.